# jQuery .offset(position) not working properly

Tags: jquery, positioning

Ok, continuing my adventure with this page.  Now I have this in my page (some of the things are placeholders for now):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(":input")
        .focus(function() {
            var localOffset = 20;
            var hint = $(this).attr("name");     // this is the placeholder part
            if(hint !== undefined)
            {
                $('#form_entry_hint').html(hint);
                var pos = $(this).offset();
                // I added rounding because it didn't work - but still not working
                pos.left = Math.round(pos.left + $(this).width() + localOffset);
                pos.top = Math.round(pos.top - 3);
                // the following alert is for debugging - it shows the correct values
                alert("top: " + pos.top + "; left: " + pos.left);
                $('#form_entry_hint').offset(pos);    // this is the line that doesn't always work
                $('#form_entry_hint').show();
            }
        })
        .blur(function() {
            $('#form_entry_hint').hide();
        });
});
```

This works perfectly fine on the first `focus`.  However on subsequent execution, the `#form_entry_hint` is being placed waaay down and to the right.  Although the debugging shows the correct values (286, 418), when it's placed with `.offset(pos)`, it ends up at (1199, 1692) - or somewhere near there with these numbers being different every time - but always way out of place.

What am I missing this time? :)

Comment: I don't want to use an external tooltip library, as the overall logic will be more complicated than this.

Comment: I've seen similar issues with offset, depending on where the node (form_entry_hint in your case) is positioned in the dom. Make sure it's attached to the document and not a child of another element.

Also, offset() seems to take scrolling into account. Seen a lot of posts mentioning subtracting $(window).scrollTop(); have you considered this already?

Comment: Also, I just looked in jQuery's API; thought I'd seen a comment about hidden elms, and found this:  "Note: elem.offset({top: 100, left: 100}) does not work if elem is not visible (i.e. display:none). If you want to position an element just prior to showing the element, you have to call elem.css("top", "100px").css("top", "100px").show();"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I get more consistent results by replacing `$('#form_entry_hint').offset(pos);`

With :

```
$('#form_entry_hint').css({ top: pos.top+'px', left: pos.left+'px' });
```

You'll need to set `#form_entry_hint` to position:absolute (or relative) if you haven't already.

**EDIT:** Thanks Kato for the simplification.

Comment: This could be further simplified:  
`$('#form_entry_hint').css({
   top: pos.top+'px',
   left: pos.left+'px'
});`

Comment: If anyone is developing a phonegap app and is having the offset issue, I just confirmed that this is definitely the fix.

Comment: While this is an old answer, it worked for me in 2023!!